# Tag cleanup: [interface]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interface) is an undefined, ambiguous tag that appears to be unnecessary as a stand-alone tag.  It is used to mean:

- network interface (existing specific tag)
- user interface (existing specific tag)
- device interface (which is covered by device- and interface-specific tags).

Recommend deleting [interface] and replacing it in questions with the appropriate specific tags.

Comment: It's still present even if empty... two of the three tags are existing. How is it ended ? If it has to exist for technical reasons, is not better to write an excerpt as _obsolete ambiguous tag use instead xxx or yyy_ ?

Comment: @Hastur: my understanding is that empty tags get deleted by the system after 24 hours.  I wonder what's going on.  Maybe it got synonomized or something.

Comment: If so (synonomized or something) it is not better to write the excerpt? Let's see tomorrow :)

Comment: Tags continue to appear "alive" after they have been cleaned up, or even not created at all.  If it *had* an excerpt and does not now then it is effectively dead as far as the system is concerned. Random words requested via `/questions/tagged` will show up as if the tag *has* been created.  Case in point: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flughafen  Just rest happy knowing you've done some good work. A way to test this is to try to create a new question and use the `interface` tag, it will not show up in the list of suggested tags.